# TypeError: calculate_distance() got an unexpected keyword argument 'plat'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
X_df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
X_df.head()
df = pd.DataFrame(X_df)
```

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
def calculate_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    return R * c
```

```
df['distance'] = [calculate_distance(**df[['plat', 'plon', 'dlat', 'dlon']].iloc[i].to_dict()) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

After executing this i get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-54432c798f30> in <module>
----> 1 df['distance'] = [calculate_distance(**df[['plat', 'plon', 'dlat', 'dlon']].iloc[i].to_dict()) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

<ipython-input-26-54432c798f30> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df['distance'] = [calculate_distance(**df[['plat', 'plon', 'dlat', 'dlon']].iloc[i].to_dict()) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

TypeError: calculate_distance() got an unexpected keyword argument 'plat'
```

train.csv data set will look like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sgj0v8I-7vYvAiGlB7BguT7RVGQ89Bbs)
Please help

Comment: Can you share sample source data from train.csv with headers?

Comment: @Anshul I can share the exact data set due to privacy issues.Updated the question with a samall sample data set

Comment: I made some changes to your code and it worked. Kindly take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the following line of code is redundant: `df = pd.DataFrame(X_df)`
Secondly, I made a change to your function 'calculate_distance' to adapt to read keyword arguments and it worked:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')


from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
def calculate_distance(**kwargs):
    R = 6373.0

    lat1 = radians(kwargs['plat'])
    lon1 = radians(kwargs['plon'])
    lat2 = radians(kwargs['dlat'])
    lon2 = radians(kwargs['dlon'])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    return R * c

df['distance'] = [calculate_distance(**df[['plat', 'plon', 'dlat', 'dlon']].iloc[i].to_dict()) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id      plat      plon     dlat     dlon    distance
0   0  7.157170  50.12450  7.36950  50.2456   27.135248
1   1  6.916570  51.25600  7.15480  51.3624   28.984844
2   2  7.275860  50.36900  7.69800  50.2540   48.637155
3   3  6.903560  51.36900  6.36540  50.1265  149.760252
4   4  7.857170  50.14780  6.14860  51.2690  226.797564
5   5  6.968457  51.39700  7.36840  50.7850   80.874454
6   6  7.278600  50.97845  7.36940  50.6974   32.609517
7   7  7.903560  50.69740  7.41260  51.6456  117.932609
8   8  6.789000  51.36000  7.14560  50.2650  127.237456
9   9  6.796000  50.01000  6.12547  51.3690  167.698477
```